# Deleted Question: Impact to Reputation

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Let's say I have an answer that gave me 4 upvotes and the following things occur:

1. The OP deleted the question.
2. The OP edited his question drastically that it has become a candidate for moderator deletion (and eventually gets deleted by the mods)

What will happen to the reputation points I gained?

Comment: Regardless of the reason, if your answer gets deleted before it's 60 days old and has a score of less than 3, you lose the rep you gained on it.

Comment: Aaaw! Too bad. :(

Answer (score 5):

> **Reputation earned from votes on deleted posts get reversed.***
>   Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained.

From [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

<sub>* Rephrased</sub>

Answer (score 2):

After questions getting answers. it can't be deleted by OP. but he can request mod to delete it.

If moderator delete the question. you lost all the reputation which your answer earned